# How to change the colour of region/endregion in VS Code?

Tags: syntax, visual-studio-code, customization

Does anyone know how to change the colour of #region/#endregion? This is greyish in VS Community but not on VS Code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the terms #region/#endregion are part of a comment, looking at their scopes with the command `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes` gives you only a `comment` scope so if you change the comment scope by the following tokenColorCustomization:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": "#ffa600b0"
}
```

will change **all** comments - probably not what you want. Plus you can only change the fontColor and fontStyle (like italics) there.

Better is using the extension [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) to find, via a regex, what you want to highlight.

Using `//#region` - your language may have different comment indicators at the start.  If so, modify the first capture group `(//\\s*)` below.

```
  "highlight.regexes": {

    "(//\\s*)(#region|#endregion)": [

      // the first capture group, the '//' uncolored here, but must have the entry below
      //  you could color those separately if you wish
      {},

      // capture group: #region or #endregion
      {
        // "overviewRulerColor": "#ffcc00",
        "backgroundColor": "#f00",
        "color": "#fff",
        // "fontWeight": "bold",
        "borderRadius": "3px",
      },
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I see, it's a shame you can't customise them separately. Thank you for the help!

Comment: how to change the region name color too and comment //

Comment: What does your comment syntax look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this extension. Works perfectly for me now.

[Better Comments - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments)

Here's my settings. You can only use "region" and "endregion" for yourself.

```
    "better-comments.tags": [
        {
            "tag": "region -",
            "color": "rgba(0,96,100,5)",
            "strikethrough": false,
            "underline": false,
            "backgroundColor": "transparent",
            "bold": false,
            "italic": false
        },
        {
            "tag": "region",
            "color": "#00F5FF",
            "strikethrough": false,
            "underline": false,
            "backgroundColor": "transparent",
            "bold": false,
            "italic": false
        },
        {
            "tag": "endregion",
            "color": "rgba(0,96,100,10)",
            "strikethrough": false,
            "underline": false,
            "backgroundColor": "transparent",
            "bold": false,
            "italic": false
        },
        {
            "tag": "!",
            "color": "#FF2D00",
            "strikethrough": false,
            "underline": false,
            "backgroundColor": "transparent",
            "bold": false,
            "italic": false
        },
        {
            "tag": "?",
            "color": "#3498DB",
            "strikethrough": false,
            "underline": false,
            "backgroundColor": "transparent",
            "bold": false,
            "italic": false
        },
        {
            "tag": "//",
            "color": "#474747",
            "strikethrough": true,
            "underline": false,
            "backgroundColor": "transparent",
            "bold": false,
            "italic": false
        },
        {
            "tag": "todo",
            "color": "#FF8C00",
            "strikethrough": false,
            "underline": false,
            "backgroundColor": "transparent",
            "bold": false,
            "italic": false
        },
        {
            "tag": "*",
            "color": "#98C379",
            "strikethrough": false,
            "underline": false,
            "backgroundColor": "transparent",
            "bold": false,
            "italic": false
        },
    ],
```

[Here's how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM3Iz.png)